# TcpSendingMessageHandler with TcpReceivingChannelAdapter collaboration

Tags: spring, sockets, tcp, spring-integration

In Spring Integration, I am using a couple of channel adapters for sending/receiving messages from a server socket. I always  create client connections with the following adapters:

```
@Bean
public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter tcpIn(AbstractClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws Exception {
    TcpReceivingChannelAdapter receiver = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
    receiver.setOutputChannel(fromTcp ());
    receiver.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    return receiver;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toTcp")
public TcpSendingMessageHandler tcpOut(AbstractClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws Exception {
    TcpSendingMessageHandler sender = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
    sender.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    sender.setClientMode(true);
    return sender;
}
```

The problem here is the server is answering in the same socket to the remote port (my opened socket port) . For example, If I connect a socket to 127.0.0.1:4444 the server is answering to my opened port (dynamic with Socket tcp) 6873 instead 4444.It is using the same socket.

A quick answer could be to use a `TcpOutboundGateway`  but I have a couple of problems with this scenario:

- I need to manage the connection events without taking into account
  send /read operations. For instance, I have to auto-connect and open
  the Socket before sending any message.
- According to the documentation:

> for high-volume messages, consider    using a collaborating pair of
>   channel adapters. However, you will    need to provide collaboration
>   logic.

Which component should I use for request/response sockets in a high-volume scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Just read the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html/ip.html#_collaborating_outbound_and_inbound_channel_adapters) from the words:

> To achieve high-volume throughput (avoiding the pitfalls of using gateways as mentioned above) you may consider configuring a pair of collaborating outbound and inbound channel adapters.

Also take a look into TCP Multiplex [Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/tcp-client-server-multiplex):

> This sample demonstrates how to configure collaborating channel adapters, on both the client and server sides, and one technique for correlating the responses to the corresponding request.